# How to get download complete event and downloaded file details in Cordova

Tags: cordova, react-native, phonegap

I'm trying to create a hybrid application using Cordova to download a pdf file and need to read the downloaded file from application.

Now i'm trying to achieve this from [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/9.x/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/#page-toc-source) .

```
window.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=sample+pdf+download&oq=sample+pdf+download', '_system', 'location=yes');
```

So with this code line i could download the file and view it internally on the app.

But i need to get the downloaded completed event and downloaded file name. Because i need to read the file internally.( might need a another plugin)

I need to develop a hybrid application. so if there are any other good technologies to achieve this goal i would love to know.
(React native ,.. etc )

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a File Opener Plugin for Cordova like fileOpener2
https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2
in this way you can use the plugin:

```
cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
'/Download/starwars.pdf', // You can also use a Cordova-style file uri: cdvfile://localhost/persistent/Downloads/starwars.pdf
'application/pdf',
{
    error : function(e) {
        console.log('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
    },
    success : function () {
        console.log('file opened successfully');
    }
});
```

Comment: hi @stg ,  i have also look into the file opener. it is only useful when we know the pdf name and url. In my situation i don't know the Download url.
What i need is surf in the internet and if we go to pdf download link app should be able to get the download complete event and downloaded file name. and then i can use your file-open plugin.

Comment: Hello, 
you must download file in a specific folder or you can use cordova-plugin-file-transfer (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file-transfer). you can create your own folder and save all the files are downloaded from your app and then you know the path to open the file

Comment: Yeah , thanks. that can do. But my requirement is i needed to use a web view to surf the internet and ten i should be able to download some files and then read it.  So problem is with cordova-plugin-inappbrowser i cannot get download complete event. Do you have any solutions for that issue ?  Thanks in advance.